# How to read values sent in Xmlhttprequest POST request on my express backend in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I want to send the values of **candid** and **candidresults** to my **/savevote** route in my express backend. How can i do that properly.

```
var candid;
var candidresults;                                                                                                   

 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'savevote', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function () {

        contractInstance.voteForCandidate(candidateName, {
      from: web3.eth.accounts[0]
    }, function () {
      console.log(contractInstance.totalVotesFor(candidateName).toString());


      candid = candidateName;
      candidresults = contractInstance.totalVotesFor(candidateName).toString();

    console.log(this.responseText);
};
xhr.send(candid);
xhr.send(candidresults);
}
```

Also,how do i access these values from my **/savevote** route that i've created below in my Express backend as shown below

```
router.post('/savevote', function (req, res, next) {


});
```

Comment: Access post params using `req.body`

Answer (score 0):

On your express, you need to use middleware in order to read the params from `req.body`

Below is a sample code

```js
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.post('/savevote', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        msg: "Echo respose"
        candid: req.body.candid,
        candidresults: req.body.candidresults
    })
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Also, from the UI, you can not call `xhr.send` multiple times.
It should be only called once as shown below

```js
xhr.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum");
```